# Export Org to S5?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is there a package to export an Org file to S5?  I've found a couple stand-alone scripts, but (a) it's difficult to know which one to use and (b) it would be nice to have a package instead of a stand-alone script.  If there is no package, is there a "canonical" script to use?

Comment: Are you talking about [S5: A Simple Standards-Based Slide Show System](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/)?

Comment: @ebpa Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/eschulte/org-S5:

> For new versions of Org-mode (>8.0) use the ox-S5.el export backend
>   now distributed in the contrib/ directory of the Org-mode repository.

It looks like you should just install `org-plus-contrib` and just require the s5 export engine with:

```
(require 'ox-s5)
```

To install `org-plus-contrib`, first add the [Org Emacs lisp Package Archive](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html) to your `package-archives`:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

Comment: Any idea how to install `org-contrib`?  I don't see it in my package list, and `(require 'ox-s5)` fails because it can't find the file.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it.  I will update the answer.